# Cassandra CompressedRandomAccessReader Out Of Memory Error

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedRandomAccessReader.<init>(CompressedRandomAccessReader.java:73) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedRandomAccessReader.open(CompressedRandomAccessReader.java:48) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.CompressedPoolingSegmentedFile.createPooledReader(CompressedPoolingSegmentedFile.java:95) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.PoolingSegmentedFile.getSegment(PoolingSegmentedFile.java:62) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.getFileDataInput(SSTableReader.java:1779) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SimpleSliceReader.<init>(SimpleSliceReader.java:57) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableSliceIterator.createReader(SSTableSliceIterator.java:65) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableSliceIterator.<init>(SSTableSliceIterator.java:42) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.SliceQueryFilter.getSSTableColumnIterator(SliceQueryFilter.java:185) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.getSSTableColumnIterator(QueryFilter.java:62) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.collectAllData(CollationController.java:273) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.getTopLevelColumns(CollationController.java:62) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getTopLevelColumns(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1925) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1758) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.getRow(Keyspace.java:342) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.SliceFromReadCommand.getRow(SliceFromReadCommand.java:57) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$LocalReadRunnable.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1494) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2179) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService.java:164) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105) [apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
```

Facing the above exception and not entirely sure how/why issue is originating the cassandra. One of the assumptions is that this is occuring during the data sync and partitioning.

The setup is 3-node cluster, with 4GB Max Heap for each node. This is especially occurring after the node has been running for a long-time (say 100 days)

The java version being used is 1.5

Comment: how much space is allocated for java heap, etc.? But it's really too little memory for Cassandra

Comment: min heap is 500MB and max heap is 4GB

Comment: So Java 1.5 is your first problem.  That version was released 16 years ago, and deprecated 5 years ago.  Cassandra 2.0 (which is also deprecated) allows Java 1.8, which you should definitely upgrade to before doing anything else.